# Erro de conexão com banco de dados Interbase

Tags: banco-de-dados, delphi, delphi-10

Estou com problema para configurar a conexão com o banco de dados no Delphi 10.3 Community Edition. Estou tentando fazer a conexão com o Interbase pelo FireDac e dá o erro abaixo quando testo a conexão.

ERRO:

> [FireDac][Phys][IB]Unable to complete network request to host
> "DESKTOP-JH05R6K". Failed to locate host machine.
> Undefined service gds_db/tcp..

Depois que coloquei esta linha abaixo no arquivo services do windows começou a dar o erro abaixo:

> gds_db     3050/tcp      # Firebird

ERRO:

> [FireDac][Phys][IB]Unable to complete network request to host
> "DESKTOP-JH05R6K/3050". Failed to establish a connection. Nenhuma
> conexão pôde ser feita porque a máquina de destino as recusou
> ativamente.

Como resolvo este erro?

Answer (score -1):

Como está passando os parâmetros de conexão? Tente algo parecido com a conexão abaixo

```
Conexao: TFDConnection;
....
Conexao.Close;
Conexao.Params.Values['Server'] := 'localhost';
Conexao.Params.Values['Port'] := '3050';
Conexao.Params.Values['Database'] := 'C:\Banco\Banco.gdb';
Conexao.Params.Values['User_Name'] := 'Usuario';
Conexao.Params.Values['Password'] := 'Senha';
Conexao.Open;
```